# Should a mechanical power switch float or ground main power when the system is off?

Tags: power-supply, power, switches

Whenever I've put a mechanical switch on a design to allow a battery to be connected / disconnected, I've always just floated system power whenever the switch is open, like this:
[image: Schematic with floated "off" state]

However, a colleague asked during a design review whether it makes more sense to ground system power when the device is off:
[image: Schematic with grounded "off" state]

From a basic functionality perspective, I believe that either should work. However, I was curious if there is a particular reason to choose to float or ground the main supply in the "off" state?

---

Edit: Several (very helpful!) initial answers and comments discuss potential harms or considerations if we do choose to ground the input. Are there any extra risks or considerations for leaving the input floating (the first design)?

Comment: Connecting to ground would have an immediate effect as C60 discharges immediately. But be care of the answer below by Spehro. If there is no need for immediate shut down (less than 10 microseconds) then better not to ground it.

Comment: Sometimes it may be deemed undesirable to allow capacitors to remain charged when the battery is disconnected. If you ground the rail the caps will discharge. It may be desirable to add a resistor so that the caps are not discharged too fast (thus making a big spark when the contact closes). But it depends on how much capacitance you have.

Comment: Also consider that the leakage electricity though the batery monitoring circuit may give some power to your microcontroller, and other parts though the ESD diodes

Comment: I'd be a tiny bit concerned about low quality or unintentionally substituted switches having some sort of make-before-break behavior, if not from the factory, then later in life after some wear. I think you'd need to toss in the large resistor others have mentioned, at a minimum.

Comment: @mkeith Do you have any specific examples of cases where it's important to drain caps (particularly on a lower-voltage board; e.g. the input here is a 3~4.2V LiPo battery)?

Comment: These things argue in favor of deliberate discharge: accessible contacts, high voltage, large capacitance, undesirable behavior visible to user during discharge. If the voltage is low, the capacitance is small, and the contacts are not accessible to the user, there is no reason to force discharge the caps that I can see. An example of undesirable behavior might be an LED blinking or gradually dimming instead of turning off crisply, or some kind of partial reboot followed by low voltage crash of the processor, or a sporadic audio output.

Answer (score 10):

Shorting the input to ground can damage some regulators because the output capacitors and multifarious bypass capacitors which may be connected to the output discharge through the regulator. It's not necessarily easy to tell from the datasheet whether that is true. You could add a resistor between the switch and ground to reduce the chances of that happening.

Some regulators have a pull-down transistor on the output to quickly discharge the output capacitors so you can reset (say) a micro by quickly cycling the power. This particular one does not seem to. Discharging the *input* capacitor with a switch takes you part of the way there, but there is no guarantee the output capacitors will be discharged quickly (though they probably will).

Comment: One can completely prevent damaging the regulator by a resistor between the switch and ground and a reverse diode across the regulator. In a lot of cases the power switch turns on/off not only the regulator, but also other things that can suck capacitors quick.

Comment: Thanks, learnt a new word today.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to ground it, perhaps then through a high resistor, to avoid any instantaneous current spikes upon switching, or any severe back draining.

Generally, I connect input signal pins to ground, even internally unconnected pins. Open pins on active devices (which is not your case - yours is a power pin) can cause undesired noise or even signalling at device internals.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask what you are trying to achieve by switching the DC in to GND. No obvious benefit in most/typical applications, but with all the risks mentioned by others (back-driving the regulator, contact arcing due to C60 discharge, etc).